# ,spe2, using jquery to add html to the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding some elements the dom using jquery. In my case Im using this function:

```
    function addMessage(message){
        var html = "...";
        html += "<a href='#' onclick='listen()'>";
        html += "...";
        $("#chat-main").append(html);
    }
```

When I call this function I can see in the dom:
`<a href="#"  onclick="listen,spe2,,spe1,">`

Whas happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is `html="..." & html+= "..."` that could be a problem.

Comment: Check answer below please @Pablo Flores

Comment: "..." is not the problem. I removed the code by confidenciality reasons. In fact I remove the "listen" and everything works well.

Comment: you can use jquery also to fire events as well for that you can add a class or id selector and can bind a event to it as follows  lets say you id is #listenerTest   now you can $("#listenerTest").click(function(){ here you can place your code inside brackets}); if you need help i can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can create a html element with jquery and can insert it to the DOM

```
    var html = $("<a href='#' onclick='listen()'/>");

    $("#chat-main").append(html);
```

Further you can set the text of any element by using following

```
$("p").text("your text will go here.");
```

Comment: This fix my problem. However I want to know why it's happening that. any idea?

Comment: Sure, the way you are creating does not make sense because to create HTML elements that you have to add to DOM you need to use $("--").this operator create a HTML element that you can add to DOM.if you want to set text/val of element then you can use    var ttt="anyvalue------";and can set it as follows   $("p").text(ttt);hope you got the point

Comment: If i want to add message as parameter what should I do?

I want "onclick='listen(message)'" where message is whatever.

Comment: here is how you can do   var message=" Your Message Here"; then you can add it as follows $("#your_selector").text(message);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addMessage(message){
var html = $("<a href='#' onclick='listen()'/>");

$("#chat-main").append(html);
$("p").text(message);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    addMessage("It's me"); // this you can call on onclick or by other events can remove from document.ready.

});
```

Html

```
<p>hello</p>
<div id="chat-main"></div>
```

home it helps.